# If $a$ is an infinite cardinal number, prove that $\aleph_0 + a = a$

Tags: elementary-set-theory

The statement I am trying to prove is:

If $a$ is an infinite cardinal number, prove that $\aleph_0 + a = a$

Any idea on how to start would be appreciated. I am thinking of proving it by showing that $\omega \cup A \approx A$. But how would I start?

---

Addition: Since $\omega \cup A$ is an infinite set, this implies that $\omega \cup A$ is equipotent with a proper subset of itself, namely $A$. This means that $\#(\omega \cup A)=\#A$.

Is this correct?

Comment: We certainly have $A\le \omega\cup A$. You just need to show the other direction, then by Cantor Bernstein you are done. Do you know that for every inifnite cardinal set, there is an injection from $\omega$ into it, and that every infinite cardinal set can be injected into proper subset of itself?

Comment: You'll need some form of the Axiom of Choice; it is not necessarily true in bare ZF.

Comment: @user160738 So for showing the other direction, since every infinite set can be injected into proper subset of itself, there is an injection from $\omega \cup A$ to $A$ which means we only need to show that such a map is surjective. Am I on the right track?

Comment: @CrusoJames no you aren't. You know that it injects to a proper subset, but not to *any* proper subset.

Comment: @OpenBall But isn't $A$ a proper subset of $\omega \cup A$? I am very confused..

Comment: @CrusoJames: Compare the two statements: (1) "There exists a proper subset $B$ of $\omega \cup A$ such that there is an injection from $\omega \cup A$ to $B$."  (2) "For every proper subset $B$ of $\omega \cup A$, there is an injection from $\omega \cup A$ to $B$."  (1) is always true.  You want to use (2) here and that needs the axiom of choice.

Answer (score 0):

For an infinite set $A$ you need to show that it contains a subset $A_0$ equipotent
to $\omega$. This requires dependent choice. So $a=\aleph_0+b$
for some cardinal $b$ (that of the complement of $A_0$ in $A$). Then
$\aleph_0+a=\aleph_0+\aleph_0+b=\cdots$ etc.